# Order SQL query results depending on the matched condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column_a = 'foo' OR column_b = 'foo' ORDER BY column_c;`.

Is there a way to have in the results first the rows matching the first condition `column_a = 'foo'` (ordered by `column_c` value) and then the rows matching the second condition `column_b = 'foo'`(ordered by `column_c` value)?

Comment: What about the case where there's a match on both column_a = 'foo' and column_b = 'foo'?  Where should they go in the ordering, or should that case be ignored?

Comment: they should go among the first columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order the rows by boolean expressions, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE column_a = 'foo' OR column_b = 'foo' 
ORDER BY column_a <> 'foo', column_b <> 'foo', column_c;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE column_a = 'foo' OR column_b = 'foo'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN column_a = 'foo' then 1 ELSE 2 END, column_c
```

Likewise, if you had another `OR` condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE column_a = 'foo' OR column_b = 'foo' OR column_c = 'foo'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN column_a = 'foo' then 1 WHEN column_b = 'foo' then 2 ELSE 3 END, column_d
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `order by column_a, column_b, column_c`, that would order the rows